# Did Harry Potter ever start looking up to his father again?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

It is known that after experiencing Snape's memories of being bullied by James Potter, Harry felt "miserable and cold" when thinking of his father.

Did that ever change back to normal, or did Harry continue harboring ill feelings towards his father?

Answer (score 8):

### Yes

In the *Deathly Hallows*, Harry is described as having good feeling when recognizing his father in a photograph.

> **With a leap of pleasure, Harry recognized his father**; his untidy black hair stuck up at the back like Harry’s, and he too wore glasses.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - Chapter Ten</sub>

Harry also later wonders whether his father would approve his actions.

> He could not keep the plea out of his voice. Hermione looked sympathetic, Ron uncertain. Harry looked down at his feet, thinking of his father. Would James have backed Harry in what he had said to Lupin, or would he have been angry at how his son had treated his old friend?
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - Chapter Eleven</sub>

Answer (score 2):

when Harry was having doubts about his father, Lupin justified their actions. (please don't ask me for the exact words) that they were young and made mistakes. also he said snape was no less innocent and was already inclined to join the dark lord. This was the first step towards healing his feelings about his father. as the story progressed, he realized that even though it was wrong, it was a mistake and the more important thing is that James changed into a better man. He was less arrogant and more considerate. So it is safe to assume that harry realized that his father did become a better and good person. the biggest proof is that even Lily who used to hate him changed her mind about James. and when harry asked if they ever stopped their enmity, Lupin said james was civil with snape at least in front of lily.

We must understand that pranking is not a new concept and even Ron and Harry can be arrogant sometimes. But it was only heightened because it is the equivalent to harry and draco. and we know harry forgave and saved draco because he saw good in him. Also, we should also remember that he only ever bullied snape which was a mutual cycle but his arrogance was the only fault in regard to his actions with other students which he corrected. So harry did forgive his fathers actions when he saw his bravery during the first wizarding war and his love, kindness etc for lily.

(Personally I think if harry was not with dursleys (who continuously put him down), he would be just like his father with his fame and gave as good as he got from draco. but Lily/Molly would probably keep him more grounded though depending on the au.)